Swagger API - Generated Spring Server interprets int64 API parameter as String in Swagger GUI
For creating RestAPI-Specifications, I use https://editor-next.swagger.io as editor. When creating API endpoints and parameters for the endpoints, I set the type of the parameter (e.g. number, string, etc.) accordingly to: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/
To deploy the API, I create a spring server via the swagger editor website by Using "Generate Server > Spring" - which also includes a GUI for testing the endpoints.
As long as I use integer as parameter type (and for example format int64), the GUI interprets the API parameter of an endpoint as integer.
But as soon as I specifiy minimum and maximum of the int parameter and recreate the spring server, the GUI incorrectly interprets the parameter as string.
I created the following RestAPI specification in https://editor-next.swagger.io/
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: Optional multiline or single-line description in [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/help/) or HTML.
  version: 0.1.9

paths:
  /users/{userId}:
    get:
      summary: Returns a user by ID.
      parameters:
        - name: userId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Parameter description in CommonMark or HTML.
          schema:
            type : integer
            format: int64
      responses: 
        '200':
          description: OK

And then created the Server over the menu (Generate Server > spring).
After creation of server, I created the .jar file using maven (mvn package) and JAVA 8:
mvn package && java -jar target\swagger-spring-1.0.0.jar

As soon as I open the GUI via http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/, the "userId" int parameter is correctly interpreted as integer($int64) parameter.
Now, I add in the swagger UI for the API parameter "minimum" and "maximum" as described in https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/
  /users/{userId}:
    get:
      summary: Returns a user by ID.
      parameters:
        - name: userId
          in: path
          required: true
          description: Parameter description in CommonMark or HTML.
          schema:
            type : integer
            format: int64
            minimum: 1
            maximum: 20
      responses: 
        '200':
          description: OK

After re-creating the server and starting it up, the GUI now interprets the API parameter userId as string.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I tried to recreate the problem using python-flask server, but here it works correctly. Is there something wrong with the generated spring server?

If i change
@Schema(allowableValues={ "1", "20" }, minimum="1", maximum="20"))
to @Schema()
in the generated java controller class, it works correctly. But there has to be a way of using the generated classes without manipulating them.

Looks like a codegen bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues. Also try openapi-generator to generate the server - maybe it does not have this issue.
